# fetch получаю пустой Promise

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fetch

Не понимаю, в чём ошибка, не могу получить результат

в `get_xlsx.php` написано:

```php
<?php
    echo json_encode($_FILES['xlsx']);
?>
```

```js
function sendRequestFile(method, url, body = null) {
  return fetch(url, {
    body: body,
    method: method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
  }).then(
    response => {
      return response;
    },
    error => {
      alert('Не удалось загрузить файл');
    });
}

const files__input = document.querySelector('.files__input');

files__input.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = e.target.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const action = e.target.getAttribute('action');

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('xlsx', file);


  sendRequestFile('post', action, formData)
    .then(data => {
      received_server(data)
    })
});


function received_server(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.json());
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%
}

pre {
  padding: 20px;
}

.files__input {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.files__input input[type=submit] {
  max-width: 200px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min">
<form action="get_xlsx.php" method="post" class="files__input" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="xlsx" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Хотя в Network написано, что я всё получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при вызове в `received_server` `console.log(data.json())` получаю пустой `Promise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было в функции `sendRequestFile`, в `.then` написать `return response.json()`, а не `return response`